# How can I capitalize the text that user inserts into EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, capitalization

I'm new to android and I want to know how to capitalize the text that users enter into an EditText

Comment: `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` in EditText

Comment: Alternatively, use a text change listener and capitalize through code

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in comments you can use

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

in your XML.

But user can still change it to lowercase if he likes.

If your requirement is to must bound user to UpperCase then you have to use TextWatcher in your class. When user input any text, we will change it to uppercase and set to edittext.

You can do it as follow:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        editText.setText(charSequence.toString().toUpperCase());
        editText.setSelection(i2);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};
```

In your onCreate of Activity

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add This line in the EditText

```
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

you will get the result that shown in fig

Answer (score 0):

If you use String in Kotlin you can use **capitalize()** extension

Example:

```
val lowerCase = "some text"
val upperCase = lowerCase.capitalize() // Result: "Some text"
```

In your case, you could apply that check to the text inside a TextWatcher:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
       editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
       editText.setText(charSequence.toString().capitalize());
       editText.setSelection(i2);
       editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
};
```

Then:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Here you can see internal implementation of capitalize method:

```
public actual fun String.capitalize(): String {
    return capitalize(Locale.getDefault())
}

public fun String.capitalize(locale: Locale): String {
   if (isNotEmpty()) {
       val firstChar = this[0]
       if (firstChar.isLowerCase()) {
           return buildString {
               val titleChar = firstChar.titlecaseChar()
               if (titleChar != firstChar.uppercaseChar()) {
                   append(titleChar)
               } else {
                   append(this@capitalize.substring(0, 1).uppercase(locale))
               }
               append(this@capitalize.substring(1))
           }
       }
   }
   return this
}
```

This method returns a copy of this string having its first letter titlecased using the rules of the default locale, or the original string if it's empty or already starts with a title case letter.
The title case of a character is usually the same as its upper case with several exceptions. The particular list of characters with the special title case form depends on the underlying platform.